# Mock method on class extended by another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, extends

I have:

```
public class A extends B {
    public ObjectC methodToTest() {
        return getSomething(); 
    }
}

/* this class is in other project and compiles in project I want test */
public class B {
    public ObjectC getSomething() {
       //some stuff calling external WS
    }
}
```

and on test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

   @Mock
   B bMock;

   @InjectMocks
   A classTotest;

   @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

   @Test
   public void getMethodToTestShouldReturnObjectC() {
        Mockito.when(bMock.getSomething()).thenReturn(new ObjectC());
        assertEquals(classTotest.methodToTest().getClass, ObjectC.class);
   }
}
```

But when I run test Mockito is calling B (and it fails because calls a ws...)

I read a lot of stuff about this but I can't solve it.

¿How Can I mock getSomething() to return ObjectC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mockito.when(bMock.getSomething()).thenReturn(new ObjectC());
```

This method changes only *bMock*. It doesn't change any other class *B* (or *A*) instances.

Comment: but @InjectMocks doesnt inject bMock on classToTest?

Comment: @ZaídaDeIsidroNavarro No `@InjectMocks` will actually inject mocks into to the fields of `A` of the same type and here the class `A` has no field so there is nothing to inject

Comment: Ok, sorry I missunderstood @InjectMocks, all clear thank you both!